# Can a pattern with getters and setters be avoided and still minify JavaScript with Closure ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I would like to minify JavaScript using the Closure Compiler in `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` mode. This is a pattern that I'm currently trying out:

```
var myClosure = (function () {
    var NS = {};
    NS.foo = 100;
    var MyConstructor = function (aValue) {
        this.aValue = aValue;
    };
    NS["MyConstructor"] = MyConstructor;

    MyConstructor.prototype.setAValue = function (v) {
        this.aValue = v;
    };
    NS["MyConstructor"].prototype["setAValue"] = MyConstructor.prototype.setAValue;

    MyConstructor.prototype.readAValue = function () {
        return this.aValue;
    };
    NS["MyConstructor"].prototype["readAValue"] = MyConstructor.prototype.readAValue;

    return NS;
}());
window["myClosure"] = myClosure;
```

It works fine and I can call into the minified code with this:

```
var obj = new myClosure.MyConstructor(10);
alert(obj.readAValue());
obj.setAValue(100);
alert(obj.readAValue());
```

A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mc0svcwc/) to demonstrate.

While the above works, it will be very cumbersome to write all the getters and setters that this project will need in order to be able to call into the compiled code.

Is there a pattern that I can use that will allow me to avoid using getter / setter methods?

Or, if not, is there a way for me to judge if refactoring the code to get it to be callable with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`is going to be worth the effort. (I estimate that adding the methods will add over 5% in terms of number of lines to the uncompiled code) Also, I currently have about 1,300 QUnit assertion tests. To run these tests, there are close to 10,000 assignments made that will have to be rewritten from something like:

```
obj.ValueA = 100;
obj.ValueB = 200;
```

to

```
obj.SetValueA(100);
obj.SetValueB(200);
```

in order to test the minified code.

So, if possible, a different approach is definitely in order.

Comment: Once you assign something like `MyConstructor.prototype.setAValue`, there's no need to do the assignment again via the NS property reference, because you're just updating the exact same prototype object.

Comment: @Pointy, You are speaking of this line `NS["MyConstructor"].prototype["setAValue"] = MyConstructor.prototype.setAValue;`, right? That line is necessary for Closure. Otherwise, when it renames `setValue` to say `Ba` the calls from outside the compiled code will break. The construction with the quote marks sets up an alias.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the assignment with quote marks is exactly identical to the assignment without quote marks. That is, the `.` and `[ ]` operators do exactly the same thing to an object once the value of the property name is determined; the only difference is that `.` requires the property name to be an identifier, and its value is determined at parse time, not at runtime.

Comment: @Pointy To see what I mean take a look at the fiddle referenced in the question. There you'll see the minified code. Closure changes `MyConstructor.prototype.setAValue` to `a.prototype.c`. In order to be able to call the method outside the closure i.e. from non-minified code, there needs to be an alias created that is not renamed. The quoted string construct creates the alias. In Closure Compiler's terms, this is an `export`. There is no way to know how a method will be renamed, so an export is required if the code is to be called from external code. The two constructs need to be identical.

Comment: **Oh I see** - sorry; I completely misunderstood the whole point of your question. My apologies. I'll start over :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@expose` was created for just this purpose.

```
/** @expose */
MyConstructor.prototype.aValue
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I was aware of `@expose` but I didn't pay much attention to it because it's [not documented](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#tags) and I therefore didn't think about it's application. Thank you for pointing it out.